# Why is my guard creep not attacking enemies?

Tags: javascript, screeps

So i created a guard creep;

```
Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([Game.ATTACK, Game.ATTACK, Game.TOUGH, Game.TOUGH, Game.MOVE], "guard1", {role:"guard"});
```

and then i have this as my main:

```
var harvester = require('harvester');
var guard = require('guard');

for(var nam in Game.creeps) {
    var creep = Game.creeps[nam];

    if(creep.memory.role == 'guard') {
        guard(creep);
    }

    if(creep.memory.role == 'harvester') {
        harvester(creep);
    }

    if(creep.memory.role == 'builder') {

        if(creep.energy === 0) {
            creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
            Game.spawns.Spawn1.transferEnergy(creep);
        }
        else {
            var targets = creep.room.find(Game.CONSTRUCTION_SITES);
            if(targets.length) {
                creep.moveTo(targets[0]);
                creep.build(targets[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the guard script

```
module.exports = function (creep) {

    var targets = creep.room.find(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS);
        if(targets.length) {
            creep.moveTo(targets[0]);
            creep.attack(targets[0]);
        }else{
            creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
        }
}
```

It worked fine in the tutorial, but now in the actual simulation, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your scripts and they actually worked just fine on Survival Mode. What was the specific problem? Have you checked if you ran out of CPU Time?

Comment: I think the actual problem was that i had 3 windows open running screeps, and it was just slowing everything down.